# Difficulties when web scraping job offers on LinkedIn

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, linkedin-api, http-status-code-403

I have been trying to scrape the job offer section for LinkedIn for a while but to no avail. By the way, I know the site has its own API but I want to do it with Beautiful Soup since I learned a while ago and it is for practising purposes.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

client = requests.Session()

HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/login/en'
URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=101174742&keywords=data%20analyst&location=Canada'

html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

login_information = {
    'session_key':'<username>',
    'session_password':'<password>',
    'loginCsrfParam': '<csrftoken>',
}
try:
    p = client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_information)
    print ("Login Successful")
except:
    print ("Failed to Login")
```

All good until here. I get "Login Succesful" but then when I ask for the "status code" I get 403:

```
p.status_code
Output: 403
```

And of course I can't scrape any info. How can I do it in the proper way?

Comment: How to do this the proper way? Most likely with the API you already found. Many sites have anti-scrapping mechanisms in place to prevent scripts from floading them. I would strongly suggest not using beautifulsoup and going for the API instead. The chance of you getting blocked are present as well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You don't really have to re-invent the wheel. There's a module called, surprise, surprise, [linkedin-api](https://github.com/tomquirk/linkedin-api) for accessing all sorts of LinkedIn data (including jobs) via so-called `Voyager` service.

Example usage:

```
from linkedin_api import Linkedin

# Authenticate using any Linkedin account credentials
api = Linkedin('reedhoffman@linkedin.com', '*******')

# GET a profile
profile = api.get_profile('billy-g')

# GET a profiles contact info
contact_info = api.get_profile_contact_info('billy-g')

# GET 1st degree connections of a given profile
connections = api.get_profile_connections('1234asc12304')
```

I'm sharing this because you might have a really hard time scraping LinkedIn with good old `BeautifulSoup` and `requests`. Also, a note of caution, do not use your personal account for any scraping activities on LinkedIn.